# vim auto indenting new lines - how to disable this behavior?

Tags: ssh, vim, fedora, putty

So let's say I have the following code:

```
if (true) {
    // do stuff
    // do additional stuff
}
```

I open up vim in PuTTY and right click to paste the above code into vim and it gets pasted like this:

```
if (true) {
        // do stuff
        //      // do additional stuff
        //      }
```

It's like it's auto-indenting every time a new line is encountered and the additional tabs just indent it that much further. And it also seems to be assuming that if the previous line was a comment that the next line will be one as well.

Even if I wasn't trying to copy / paste into vim it's not behavior I like but, the fact that I am makes the input barely usable.

Is there any way to disable this behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to focus on the correct issue, the auto indenting is simply because of the commenting it. So the question is more like ***vim auto commenting out some pasted lines***

Comment: Does the info in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84639/vim-commenting-out-what-i-paste explain/address your question?

Comment: `:set paste`, or `set nopaste` to undo

Comment: The comment of @Panki should be the official answer. There is nothing too easy.